# Hard drive enclosure for single SATA drive that has USB and Ethernet connections

Tags: sata, enclosures

Does anyone know where I could get a hard drive enclosure for 1 SATA drive that has USB 2 and Ethernet connectivity?

Im looking to have a hard drive connected directly to my Samsung TV but also have it on the network.

Any suggestions?

I see one here, but its over $100 (im looking to go cheaper), plus it looks like it got some bad reviews: http://www.newegg.ca/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16817347023CVF

Comment: "Also"? As in have it connected to USB and Ethernet at the same time?

Comment: Yes - the USB will go into the TV and the ethernet to the router

Comment: Shopping/buying recommendations are off-topic for SU - please see FAQ.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you're going to find something that will let you connect to both simultaneously. Your best bet is to put it on the network via Ethernet and have a media device that will connect to the network and output to the TV.

Answer (score 0):

This is somewhat a shopping recommendation post, and possibly runs afoul of the FAQ. However, I didn't expect to find this, so I wanted to post it more as a "this exists" than a referral - [http://www.amazon.com/gp/aw/d/B000E1D36S/ref=aw_d_detail?pd=1](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000E1D36S)

Learn something new every day.